# Limit of Sum related question

Tags: calculus, limits

> For $a\in R$ &  $a \ne 1$
> $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{1^a} + {2^a} + ... + {n^a}}}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{a - 1}}\left[ {\left( {na + 1} \right) + \left( {na + 2} \right) + .. + \left( {na + n} \right)} \right]}} = \frac{1}{{60}}$$, then find the value of $a$.

---

My approach is as follows:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{1^a} + {2^a} + ... + {n^a}}}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{a - 1}}\left[ {\left( {{n^2}a + \frac{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{2}} \right)} \right]}} = \frac{1}{{60}}$$

How to I convert it into limit of sum so that I can proceed with the integration?

Comment: Hint: Stolz-Cesaro, the discrete version of L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing numerator and denominator of the given expression by $n^a$, we  get $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sum_{r=1}^n(\frac rn)^a}{\frac{(n + 1)^{a - 1}}{n^a}\sum_{r=1}^n\left( na + r\right)} = \frac{1}{{60}}$$
 $$\implies \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{(n+1)\sum_{r=1}^n(\frac rn)^a}{(\frac{n + 1}{n})^{a}\cdot n\sum_{r=1}^n\left( a + \frac rn\right)} = \frac{1}{{60}}$$ 
 Now, divide numerator and denominator by $n$ and you would be able to convert limit into integration. $a$ would come out to be $7, -\frac{17}2$. Doubt?